# Why SMS sending is failing using plivo in R?

Tags: r, api, ubuntu, sms

I am trying to use R script to send SMS internationally. I am using correctly Auth ID and Token, both numbers are verified. But I haven't bought any number from "Plivo". Is this the reason my message is not sent?

The code is getting compiled without any error. But no SMS is sent or received. I am sharing my code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(httr) 

AUTH_ID="**************"
AUTH_TOKEN="**************************"
message<-"Eddie is confirming the message"
url="https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/**************/Message/"     
POST(url,authenticate(AUTH_ID,AUTH_TOKEN),body=list
(src="+966123456789",dst="+4912345678910",text=message))
```

Can anybody please tell me that what could be the possible reasons that why message sending is not happening even the source code is correct?

Comment: You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have tried to rephrase the question. Hopefully, at least it will be understandable.

Comment: Can you print the response you are getting . Also I would try adding  'encode = "json"' in your POST request.

Answer (score 1):

> But I haven't bought any number from "Plivo"

The answer is: 
To send an SMS with Plivo, you need a Plivo bought number.

Obvious logic:
If this was not the case, anyone could send messages from any "verified" phone numbers?

If you meant verified as in "account verified":
This is not what Plivo is used for, you need to check if your Mobile Carrier is providing an accessible internet accessible API (I doubt it.) If you need to use sim-linked numbers, you can always use modems and AT commands, but it's fairly unreliable.

I think you should buy a $1 Plivo number, unless you need it to validate gmails or things of such.

Comment: where are the code-highlighted chunks?  are they quotations from somewhere else (in which case you should probably use quote markup, `>`, so that the words wrap properly)?  Or are you just trying to emphasize these phrases (in which case you should probably boldface or something rather than using code highlighting)

Comment: oof... let me properly rephrase that, you're right.